# Why can't I use the same patch on several matplotlib.axes?

Tags: python, matplotlib, graphics

Using `matplotlib`, I wanted to draw two nearly identical pictures side-by-side, so I first started trying to draw two identical pictures and I got an error stating that I was using twice an `Artist` and that this was not supported.

Here you can find an example where the error occurs.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches

fig = plt.figure()
ax_1 = fig.add_subplot(1,2,1)
ax_2 = fig.add_subplot(1,2,2)

thing = patches.Polygon([[0,0],[0,1],[1,1],[1,0]], closed = True)

# Add patches
ax_1.add_patch(thing)
#ax_2.add_patch(thing)

plt.show()
```

If I uncomment the `ax_2.add_patch(thing)` line, I get the error

`ValueError: Can not reset the axes.  You are probably trying to re-use an artist in more than one Axes which is not supported`.

I did not know that a `patch` was an `Artist`, neither did I know that an `Artist` can only be used once (I may not have understood what an `Artist` is...).

Since I think that `matplotlib` should be able to draw twice the same square on two different `axes`, I can deduce that I did not ask `matplotlib` the right way.

**What would be the proper way to ask `matplotlib` to draw twice the same patch on two different `axes`?**

EDIT: According to @HMH1013n, I tried the following code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches

fig = plt.figure()
ax_1 = fig.add_subplot(1,2,1)
ax_2 = fig.add_subplot(1,2,2)

# Add patches
thing = patches.Polygon([[0,0],[0,1],[1,1],[1,0]], closed = True)
ax_1.add_patch(thing)
thing = patches.Polygon([[0,0],[0,1],[1,1],[1,0]], closed = True)
ax_2.add_patch(thing)

plt.show()
```

an the error does not occur. Each call of `patches.Polygon` creates a new patch, so each can be used in an `axes`. Is this the right way to do?

Comment: Create un function like :  `def generate_thing():
    return patches.Polygon([[0,0],[0,1],[1,1],[1,0]], closed = True)`, Then cal the function in `add_patch`.

Comment: Matplotlib stores the transformation needed to draw the polygon onto a given subplot directly into the "patch".  If you need the polygon onto more than one subplot, you need to create a copy.